# Get latitude and longitude automatically using php, API

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

In one of my php applications I have to find out the latitude and longitude of the place from  address.

I tried this code:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=$region");
$json = json_decode($json);

$lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
$long = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
```

But it is showing the following Error :

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=technopark, Trivandrun, kerala,India&sensor=false&region=IND) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in D:\Projects\lon.php on line 4

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use `curl` instead of `file_get_contents`:

```
$address = "India+Panchkula";
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=India";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response_a = json_decode($response);
echo $lat = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
echo "<br />";
echo $long = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

Comment: Does anyone know the purpose of specifying CURLOPT_PROXYPORT 3128??

Comment: Oops - went past the 5-minute limit on comment-editing... I'm not the least bit familiar with using proxies, but from my reading on the subject, I would expect that since there is no proxy *server* specified, then the proxy *port* would be ignored. Yet most every post I see on using curl to access google maps specifies this port with no server. Is this just copy-paste pollution, or is there a purpose to it?

Comment: Hi, I want to get current location according to ip address.  Is there any way to get this ?

Comment: Most of the time it gives null response.What  might be the issue.

Answer (score 37):

```
$address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);
```

Use the above code before the file_get_content.
means, use the following code

```
$address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);

$json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=$region");
$json = json_decode($json);

$lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
$long = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
```

and it will work surely.
As address does not support spaces it supports only + sign in place of space.

Comment: See built-in php functions: urlencode() and rawurlencode();

Comment: @CodeLღver i want to fetch zip code, lat, long from address.

Comment: @Manwal you means to say postal code... or are code?? may i right

Comment: @Manwal you can check the api and get what data it is returning by print `$json`. hope so you can find all data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61541/discussion-between-manwal-and-code-lver).

Answer (score 8):

```
//add urlencode to your address
$address = urlencode("technopark, Trivandrun, kerala,India");
$region = "IND";
$json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=$region");

echo $json;

$decoded = json_decode($json);

print_r($decoded);
```

Comment: The url should be `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=$region`

Comment: @ThomasOrlita thanks. The problem was &reg changed to different character, so used &amp;region instead

Answer (score 4):

Two ideas:

- Are Address and Region [URL Encoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)?
- Perhaps your computer running the code doesn't allow http access. Try loading another page (like 'http://www.google.com') and see if that works. If that also doesn't work, then there's something wrong with PHP settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
$address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);

$json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=$region");
$json = json_decode($json);

$lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
$long = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
```

Answer (score 0):

...and don't forget "$region" for the code to work:

```
$address = "Salzburg";
$address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);
$region = "Austria";

$json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=$region");
$json = json_decode($json);

$lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
$long = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
echo $lat."</br>".$long;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **allow_url_fopen** on your apache server is disabled. you need to trun it on.

kindly change **allow_url_fopen = 0**  to **allow_url_fopen = 1**

Don't forget to restart your Apache server after changing it.