# How to show the location of the user, as in facebook?

Tags: php, html, tracker

I have searched in many places but I couldn't find the answer for this.

The thing is I want to display the users current location in the Web page just as a text without using Maps and pointing to that.

Many places I saw used Maps for implementation, is there any way ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Google Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use HTML5 Geolocation feature: http://html5demos.com/geo

Comment: Thanks but it says, location failed

Comment: Your browser should ask you about the permission - you have to grand it.

Answer (score 1):

try the google maps api (v3) geocoding stuff:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingAddressTypes

there would be a possibility to simple write down the current location (as street or city)

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 Geolocation has already been mentioned, but I recommend you use [PHP Geo IP Location](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) as a fallback - it derives a coarse location from the IP address even if the user doesn't allow the HTML5 location request or uses a browser, that doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

In your webpage use JavaScript to get client IP. Then use IP to location conversion web services to map the IP address of the client to the physical location.

Answer (score 0):

By lattitude and Longitude values only you can the location
you can use this  following link in your program.This link will return a xml file having details and you can parse and get the location name.Hope it helps

http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceName?lat=47.3&lng=9&username=demo

and once check this post

[Get latitude and longitude automatically using php, API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633574/get-latitude-and-longitude-automatically-using-php-api)

First you need a geographic location for each hotspot ideally using latitude and longitude. You can use the Google Geocoding API to go through each record and store lat/long.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it is pretty simple to implement. Hope this works for you. All the best!
http://gonga.in/simple-location-tracker-script/