# Embedding google map with address

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a MySql database with addresses and i want to embed google maps API showing one address.

How do i use google maps API to embed a map showing one of these addresses on a page.

please help

Thanks :D

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: @Bjoem I haven't tried anything yet. I haven't played with the maps API yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know the value of latitude and longitude to mark a place in the map.
You can use Google API to get the latitude and longitude. Pass this values to the Google MAP.
[Get latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633574/get-latitude-and-longitude-automatically-using-php-api) check this link to get the latitude and longitude using Google API

script for the map canvas

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:650px; height:300px"></div>
lat = latitude value from Google API
lon = longitude value from Google API
var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
zoom: 8,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
```

Comment: I dont know the  latitude and longitude. I only have an address.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633574/get-latitude-and-longitude-automatically-using-php-api Check this link. You can get latitude and longitude from address.

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry I didn't read it at first but now I get it. Thanks a lot. Ill give it a try

Comment: Okay tell me if it is working or not. Also don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an iframe pass the address from MySQL Database as an URL parameter.

```
<iframe width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.it/maps?q=<?php echo $yourAddress; ?>&output=embed"></iframe>
```