# Cakephp get address from latitude and longitude google map

Tags: google-maps, cakephp, google-maps-api-3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x .. i have implemented the google maps into my app ...i am using this helper

https://github.com/marcferna/CakePHP-GoogleMapHelper

what i want is i want to get the address on the basis of longitude and lattitude.. dont know how can i get this as i have never worked on the google maps before ...

here is code of my view page which is showing the map

```
      $map_options = array(
    'id' => 'map_canvas',
    'width' => '950px',
    'height' => '600px',
    'style' => '',
    'zoom' => 16,
    'type' => 'ROADMAP',
    'custom' => null,
    'localize' => false,
    'latitude' => $latitude,
    'longitude' =>  $longitude,
    'address' => '1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino',
    'marker' => true,
    'markerTitle' => 'This is my position',
    'markerIcon' => 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/home.png',
    'markerShadow' => 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/shadow.png',
    'infoWindow' => true,
    'windowText' => 'My Position'
);
?>



<?php echo $this->GoogleMap->map($map_options);
```

Comment: Might want to check this link for how to get longitude and latitude from an address https://stackoverflow.com/a/8633623/2003890

Comment: well i have the longitude and lattitude ... i want to retrive the address on the basic of these two ... in simple php we can do something like formatted address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So reverse geocoding basically?

Check this out:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse