# Grab text content with xpath

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath, for-loop

I want to grab name and coordinates of places from advisor.travel web site which content is CC so I need only first 10 page with name and coordinates...

Link to attractions is link format: `http://en.advisor.travel/poi/1` so `'http://en.advisor.travel/poi/'.i` where `i` is number of attraction

I want to get only first 10 attraction so i is beetween 1 and 10 and xpath for name is

```
//h1 tag
```

and xpath for coordinates is:

```
//span[@class='latitude']
//span[@class='longitude']
```

I now create a scraper and code is :

```
<?php


for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
  {
  $dom2 = new DOMDocument();
  @$dom2->loadHTMLFile('http://en.advisor.travel' . $i);
  $xpath2 = new DOMXPath($dom2);
  $data = array();
  $data[name] = $xpath2->query("//h1");
  $data[latitude] = $xpath2->query("//span[@class='latitude']");
  $data[longitude] = $xpath2->query("//span[@class='longitude']");

  } 
echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>';



?>
```

but this code for result give me only this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => DOMNodeList Object
        (
            [length] => 0
        )

    [latitude] => DOMNodeList Object
        (
            [length] => 0
        )

    [longitude] => DOMNodeList Object
        (
            [length] => 0
        )

)
```

So how I can fix it? What is problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're suppressing the errors with (`@`) operator, so you didn't notice that the URL was actually incorrect.

The call should be:

```
@$dom2->loadHTMLFile('http://en.advisor.travel/poi/' . $i);
```

Further below, you have the following:

```
$data[name] = $xpath2->query("//h1");
```

There are two things wrong with this line (and the two lines below):

- You're using a constant as key. You should wrap it in single quotes.
- Even if the above error is corrected, you'll only get the values of the last iteration of your `for` loop. To correctly push the elements into your `$data` array, you'll have to use `$data['key'][]` syntax.

Instead of simply querying the XPath, you'll hav to access the textContent of that XPath node. For that, you can use `textContent()`:

```
$data['name'][] = $xpath2->query("//h1")->item(0)->textContent;
$data['latitude'][] = $xpath2->query("//span[@class='latitude']")
                                                    ->item(0)->textContent;
$data['longitude'][] = $xpath2->query("//span[@class='longitude']")
                                                    ->item(0)->textContent;
```

The complete code should look like this:

```
<?php

for ($i=0; $i<=12; $i++)
{
    $dom2 = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom2->loadHTMLFile('http://en.advisor.travel/poi/' . $i);
    $xpath2 = new DOMXPath($dom2);
    $data = array();
    $data['title'][] = $xpath2->query("//h1")->item(0)->textContent;
    $data['latitude'][] = $xpath2->query("//span[@class='latitude']")->item(0)->textContent;
    $data['longitude'][] = $xpath2->query("//span[@class='longitude']")->item(0)->textContent;
    echo "<hr/>";
} 

echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>';

?>
```

Technically, this should work, but since there are 12 different URLs to be queried, I don't think this is a good idea and hence don't recommend it.

Comment: what is the better way to do this?

Comment: @drCode: There's no *better* way. Screen scraping is considered a very bad idea for this. Anyway, if you have the locations already, you can use [Google Maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8633574/1438393) to get the latitude and longitude :)

Comment: yes, but how I can send one by one request for scraping to this site... now I send all 10 request at same time... how I can send one by one ... etx. one request, 5 seconds pause and then again send other request...

Comment: @drCode: You can use `sleep()` -- i.e. `sleep(5)` -- you might also want to set `set_time_limit(0)` in the very top of your script to make sure you don't reach the maximum execution time limit.

Comment: @drCode: After `for ($i=0; $i<=12; $i++) {`.