# Why do people use CURLOPT_PROXYPORT 3128 without CURLOPT_PROXY?

Tags: google-maps, curl, proxy

I asked this in a comment to the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633574/get-latitude-and-longitude-automatically-using-php-api) question, but perhaps since it was a comment on an old question, and perhaps because the answer is obvious to anyone who's sure of it, it got no response. But I just wanted to get sure... I see countless examples of code accessing google maps api through php curl, where this is specified:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
```

And yet there is no `CURLOPT_PROXY` specified or mentioned. To me, that makes no sense. So I think it's just a case where someone removed the proxy line from some sample code they had before posting it, and everyone else has blindly copy-pasted it into their code and then posted that code.

Can anyone confirm that? And if it's the case that the `CURLOPT_PROXY` line was omitted, does anyone know the significance of port 3128? I don't see that port number mentioned anywhere else other than in similar code snippets using google maps.

Comment: As a meta-question, I couldn't figure out how to make a link directly to a specific answer to a question, so I just linked to the question and said "the accepted answer to". Seems like there must be a way to do it, but I haven't found one.

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](https://isc.sans.edu//port.html?port=3128),

> Port 3128 is usually used by 'squid', a very popular web proxy server
>   that is also able to proxy other protocols (e.g. ftp).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_(software)), Squid:

> has a wide variety of uses, from speeding up a web server by caching
>   repeated requests; to caching web, DNS and other computer network
>   lookups for a group of people sharing network resources; to aiding
>   security by filtering traffic.

So it seems like it isn't just an arbitrary port number.

In the future, you can link to a specific answer by clicking "share" under the answer and copying the link. For example, the link for the answer you were referring to would be https://stackoverflow.com/a/11395547/4241842.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about share - I guess I was thinking it would actively post something rather than give a permalink to copy-paste! I'd like to accept your answer, but it only addresses part of the question. Does the  CURLOPT_PROXYPORT have any purpose if CUROPT_PROXY (i.e. the server) is not also specified? Is there some sort of curl default that makes it useful, or is CURLOPT_PROXYPORT really just a useless vestige carried along from original code that used a squid proxy server? -Thx

Comment: Every other Google Maps curl example I saw, people used port 3218 without setting a proxy server. After reading more on [CURLOPT_URL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_URL.html), I found that `the host part of the URL contains the address of the server that you want to connect to`. My best guess is that since the URL they specify for geocoding (http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/...) makes a call to Google, which in turn [makes a call to an external server](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding), you don't have to set up your own proxy server.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I can't say that I agree (or maybe I just don't understand what you mean). CURLOPT_URL specifies the destination url, it is the only *required* option when using curl. Reading the documentation for both [CURLOPT_PROXYPORT](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXYPORT.html) and [CURLOPT_PROXY](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html), it seems clearer to me than ever that CURLOPT_PROXYPORT without a CURLOPT_PROXY makes no sense. OTOH, CURLOPT_PROXY can specify a port number, rendering CURLOPT_PROXYPORT completely unnecessary. So no answer yet.

Comment: Oddly enough, while your comment about "every other Google Maps curl example" matches what prompted me to ask this question, just now I did some more googling and quickly found several examples that do not use the CURLOPT_PROXYPORT option at all. So I'm thinking it really is a sloppy copy-paste explosion that caused the option to appear without a matching CURLOPT_PROXY in many posts around the web.