# how can I get the longitude and latitude coordinates of a place using php for geocoding

Tags: php, google-maps, geocoding

I want to get the longitude and latitude coordinates using php from the given address ($street, $barangay, $city and $province).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can use url:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=YOUR_ADDRESS
```

It's free.

You will get data in json encoded form which contain lat & long

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of PHP code to get the latitude and longitude values from Google Maps API, based on the town, city or country location. Check this [tutorial](https://daveismyname.com/get-longitude-and-latitude-from-an-address-with-php-and-google-maps-api-bp) and [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro).

```
<?php
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=West+Bridgford&sensor=false&region=UK";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$response = json_decode($response, true);

//print_r($response);

$lat = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$long = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

echo "latitude: " . $lat . " longitude: " . $long;
?>
```

The `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json` URL have 3 parameters: address (your main location), region and sensor that indicates whether or not the request will come from a device with a location sensor.

You can also check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633574/get-latitude-and-longitude-automatically-using-php-api). The community suggested to use `curl` instead of `file_get_contents`.

```
$address = "India+Panchkula";
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=India";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response_a = json_decode($response);
echo $lat = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
echo "<br />";
echo $long = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Maps Geocoding API, here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

It's free for:
- 2,500 free requests per day
- 10 requests per second

In order to use Google Geocoding API, use this library (MIT license):
http://geocoder-php.org/